# Materialize-ui navigation menu

Tags: navbar, materialize

How to fill navigation menu, so when it's clicked on the icon on the left (like mobile menu), a drop down menu appears?

[image]

```
/**
 * A simple example of `AppBar` with an icon on the right.
 * By default, the left icon is a navigation-menu.
 */
const AppBarExampleIcon = () => (
  <AppBar
    title="Title"
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this. this is just an example from http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import Toggle from 'material-ui/Toggle';
import MoreVertIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/close';

class Login extends Component {
  static muiName = 'FlatButton';

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatButton {...this.props} label="Login" />
    );
  }
}

const Logged = (props) => (
  <IconMenu
    {...props}
    iconButtonElement={
      <IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>
    }
    targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
    anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
  >
    <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
    <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
    <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
  </IconMenu>
);

Logged.muiName = 'IconMenu';

/**
 * This example is taking advantage of the composability of the `AppBar`
 * to render different components depending on the application state.
 */
class AppBarExampleComposition extends Component {
  state = {
    logged: true,
  };

  handleChange = (event, logged) => {
    this.setState({logged: logged});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Toggle
          label="Logged"
          defaultToggled={true}
          onToggle={this.handleChange}
          labelPosition="right"
          style={{margin: 20}}
        />
        <AppBar
          title="Title"
          iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
          iconElementRight={this.state.logged ? <Logged /> : <Login />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AppBarExampleComposition;
```

just tweak `iconElementLeft={this.state.logged ? <Logged /> : <Login />}`

Comment: I tweaked it and it helped. Thank you very much.